# Mootools : tool tip help

Tags: mootools, tooltip

I am using mootools in one of my webpages.

http://www.mstockphoto.net/drsdirect.net/pricing/tooltipsvn.html
In this page the tool tip is working fine. I am using mootools.svn.js in this webpage.

http://www.mstockphoto.net/drsdirect.net/pricing/tooltip.html
mootools-1.1-1.2-compat-core.js,mootools-1.2-core-yc.js,mootools-1.1-1.2-compat-more.js in this page.

Could any one tell the difference between using the svn and core and more file of mootools.

Thanks
Prady

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you get the `mootools-1.1-1.2-compat-core.js` file? It doesn't look like a proper MooTools build—which is most likely why it's not working. (I haven't mentioned `mootools-1.2-core-yc.js` because it doesn't seem to exist.)

`mootools.svn.js`, although it's working, is a pretty old build of MooTools (v1.11). I'd recommend that you download the latest MooTools core (v1.2.4) from the [MooTools download page](http://mootools.net/download) and download the `Tips` class from the [MooTools More Builder](http://mootools.net/more). (They've split MooTools into two parts: "Core" and "More".) Then simply link to these two files in your HTML page (or combine them into one file and just link to it).

Comment: There's also a migration page on GitHub to help move from 1.11 to 1.2.x. It has most topics covered. Most things can be solved by renaming.